# Can I carry a defibrillator in my (hand) luggage?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, hand-luggage

I'm currently living in UK and I'll be travelling to Turkey soon. I bought an automatic defibrillator for my family, and I wonder whether I can carry it in my hand luggage or checked baggage?

Thanks!

P.S. In case it matters, I'll be flying from Edinburgh to London, London to Istanbul, Istanbul to another city in Turkey.

Comment: Do you know the type and capacity of the battery? This makes all the difference and may even prevent it from flying.

Comment: @Itai Lithum, removable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We (my wife and I) flew from Heathrow to Auckland two weeks ago with two defibrillators in our hand luggage (one each) without any issues at all - we had to put them through x-ray in their own trays (both at Heathrow and at Hong Kong), but were never questioned as to what they were or why we were carrying them.

Having checked several airlines rules on this, all emergency AEDs currently purchaseable by the public fall within the battery limits - although you won't be able to fly with a spare battery or a battery that isn't inserted into the device.